# Concatenation in browser.executeScript

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, protractor

I would like to replace the requirements with the param elementLocator in browser.executeScript, Please check the below code in my test case.

```
browser.executeScript(function (arguments, elemntLocator) {
       window.CKEDITOR.instances.requirements.setData(arguments);
 }, data, elemntLocator);
```

Comment: If the `elemntLocator` has a name of a valid property of `window.CKEDITOR.instances` then `window.CKEDITOR.instances[elemntLocator].setData(arguments);`. But please don't use abbreviations like 'elemnt'. You shave off one character and leave your team prone to spelling mistakes and time wasted in debugging.

Comment: Thanks @Jacek Ciolek It's working Good.

Comment: Hi @Jacek Ciolek, up to today it was working fine, but today data entered into ckeditor, but it did n't considers the entered data. it's working fine manually but when I automate data is entered but it did n't considered. Please Help me. Thanks .

Comment: It's really hard to say from where I sit. My wild guess would be something has changed. Maybe the element locator is no longer valid?

Comment: Thanks @jacke Ciolek, I got that one.